# How to split string based on delimiters in Java

Tags: java, split, delimiter

I would like to split string based on the delimiters.

The example string is: `["INESIS","13-ARTENGO-P1046","19"]`

It should be divided into three string after splitting.

```
String data="[\"INESIS\",\"13-ARTENGO-P1046\",\"19\"]";
String[] values=data.split(",");
```

I have tried in the above way, but it isn't working.

Comment: Please show exactly what the three strings should be after successfully splitting them.

Comment: `String data="["INESIS","13-ARTENGO-P1046","19"]"` is not a valid statement in Java. It is a syntax error!

Answer (score 1):

try
`String data="[\"INESIS\",\"13-ARTENGO-P1046\",\"19\"]";`
you must put the escape character `\` before each `"` otherwise java thinks that you ended your string
This way you tell java that you didn't mean to cut the string but that `"` is part of your string

Comment: With the current version of the question, we don't yet know what the three resulting strings are supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to provide `String` in valid form.

Eg:

```
String data="[\"INESIS\",\"13-ARTENGO-P1046\",\"19\"]"; // escape "
```

Then you need to remove `[` and `]`. You can use `replaceAll("\\[|\\]","")` for that.

Then split from `,`

Eg:

```
String data="[\"INESIS\",\"13-ARTENGO-P1046\",\"19\"]";
String[] values=data.replaceAll("\\[|\\]","").split(",");
for(String i:values){ // just to print the values
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

Out put:

```
"INESIS"
"13-ARTENGO-P1046"
"19"
```

Comment: With the current version of the question, we don't yet know what the three resulting strings are supposed to look like.

Comment: Removing all the `[` and `]` characters is possibly dangerous/overkill, why not just remove the first and last characters instead?

Answer (score 0):

To split a string on the basis of other string, StringTokenizer class can be used.

Here is a code snippet for this

```
    String str = "Splitting, Using, Comma"
    System.out.println("---- Split by comma ',' ------");
    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");

    while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(st2.nextElement());
    }
```